# How can I open my chrome extension's popup page from the extension's content script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script which injects a button to the document.
I want to open the extension's popup when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot open the extension's popup programmatically. That is by design. Perhaps you can use a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageAction/) instead?

Good Luck!

Comment: Do you have any reference?